Variable might not have been initialized in Java program
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"What Do You Want To Do?");
    String typeOfMath = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Addition, Subtraction, Division, Multiplication, Find The Square Root?");

    String Addition;
    String Subtraction;
    String Division;
    String Multiplication;
    String SquareRoot;
    double z;

    if (typeOfMath == Addition) {
        double x = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First Number"));
        double y = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First Number"));
        z = x + y;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Answer Is: " + z);
    }else if (typeOfMath == Subtraction) {
        double x = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First Number"));
        double y = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First Number"));
        z = x - y;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Answer Is: " + z);
    }else if (typeOfMath == Division) {
        double x = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First Number"));
        double y = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First Number"));
        z = x / y;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Answer Is: " + z);
    }else if (typeOfMath == Multiplication) {
        double x = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First Number"));
        double y = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First Number"));
        z = x * y;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Answer Is: " + z);
    }else if (typeOfMath == SquareRoot){
        double x = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter The Number"));
        z = Math.sqrt(x);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Answer Is: " + z);
    }

    }
}

It says that strings addition, subtraction etc might not be initialized.

String Addition; you've defined a variable called Addition but haven't set it to anything, so it's uninitialized. Are you sure you need all those variables instead of just using if (typeOfMath == "Addition")

String Addition = "Addition"; - little enhancement, since it should not be changed: final String ADDITION = "Addition"; - more enhancement, use an enum (enumeration class) like enum Operation { ADDITION, SUBTRACTION, MULTIPLICATION, DIVISION, SQUARE_ROOT } - use of switch-case instead of if-else ||| please note that according Java convention, constants are all uppercases

Do not compare Strings in java via ==. See How do I compare Strings in Java? Nontheless, using an enum here is the better solution.

This should answer your question: How do I compare strings in Java?

You've declared the Addition, Subtraction, Division, etc. string objects, but you haven't actually instantiated them with a value.
String Addition = "addition"; // or similar

By looking at your code, it's likely that you just want to refactor your if statements to use literal strings instead. There's no real point to having these declared as magic strings, unless you intend to use them elsewhere in your code. If that's the case, you should declare them as final Strings in a separate constants.java (or similar) file instead.
if (typeOfMath.equals("Addition")) { // Note that this is a literal string, not an object reference
// Your addition logic goes here
} else if (typeOfMath.equals("Subtraction")) {
 //Your subtraction logic goes here
}
// And so on and so on, using literal strings for the rest of your operations


Please consider modifying your answer regarding: How do I compare Strings in Java?

I often forget that that's a thing with Java strings. Thanks for the heads up :)
